# Отображение IE в панели задач. Окна вместо вкладок

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, навигация

Работаю с очень большим количеством вкладок в браузере, группирую их в окна логическими группами. По внешним причинам вынужден использовать Internet Explorer и windows7.

При наведении на значек IE в панели задач показываются все вкеладки и выбрать из них нужную становится очень сложно из-за того, что их слишком много.

Есть ли способ настроить IE (или windows), чтобы при навигации из панели задач показывались именно открытые окна, а не вкладки?